# Remove color change after click in bootstrap button

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4

```
<button type="button" style="line-height: 0.4em;text-align: left;height:35px" class=" btn btn-success  btn-block">></button>
```

After clicked the color of the button changes a little darker indicating that it has been clicked and the button will return to normal color when clicked the mouse in the page's body. I want to suppress this effect. I tried `box-shadow:none` and `shadow-none` as well but it didn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:active` pseudo class on the button:

```
.button_class_name:active {
 background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You didn't change button_class_name to your class name